# What is this meaning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have seen [State and Lifecycle in React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). In which, I have seen the following sentence:

> However, it misses a crucial requirement: the fact that the Clock sets up a timer and updates the UI every second should be an implementation detail of the Clock.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As scrolling down on the document, you'll see the full implementation of the Clock component is this:

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {date: new Date()};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(  //<~~ The implement of updating Timer is performed inside Clock component
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {  // <~~ The implement of updating Timer is performed inside Clock component
    this.setState({
      date: new Date()
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <h2>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Notice that, the timer is now managed within the Clock component. It's different from before while the updating timer operation is performed outside of Clock component's body.

This is a flashback

```
function Clock(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function tick() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Clock date={new Date()} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000); // <~~ The increment happen outside the Clock component
```